# Extract a part of character string

Tags: regex, r

I have an expression as `FR97_6393_COROG436790`. I need to delete everything after second underscore, so that it would be `FR97_6393`.

I have tried to create `gsub` pattern for this (`"FR([0-9]+)_([0-9]+).*"`) but has failed.

Could you please help me to figure out the right pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try with `sub`

```
sub("^([^_]+_[^_]+).*", "\\1", str1)
#[1] "FR97_6393"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "FR97_6393_COROG436790"
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use sub,

```
sub("_[^_]*$", "", x)
```

This removes the last underscored part.